# what does R.id.snack do in Radio Button example?

Tags: android

In the Developer.Android example [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/RadioGroup1.html) what does the `newRadioButton.setId(R.id.snack);` do?

In these examples they use variable names that are suppose to help the learner infer what it does. So why did they choose to call it a snack here? 
Did they call it a snack to try to lead me to think of it as a radio hint?

**Edit** Found out they are calling it a 'snack' only because the previous example used food themed variables

Comment: can you elaborate your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why they called it snack.
But what the mean with :`newRadioButton.setId(R.id.snack);` 
that they give it an ID.
They made the radiobutton on previousd 2 lines, and when you give it an ID, you can use the radiobutton in the code, for example:

```
//Making RadioButton
RadioButton newRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);

//Give the RadioButton an ID
newRadioButton.setId(R.id.snack);

//making a variable called snack_choice
RadioButton snackchoice;

//Assign an radiobutton to the variable
snack_choice = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.snack);

//Use it
if (snack_choice.isChecked()) {
            //do something
        }
```

I hope you understand it.

However, I prefer to make buttons in the XML file.

Answer (score 1):

That line means you are setting and ID for the newly created `RadioButton` so that you can refer to it later in your code by that ID. The name doesn't represent something special, it could be anything, they named it *snack* because in the example the other `RadioButton` are set ID like breakfast, lunch, dinner etc.

Answer (score 1):

i know this question have an answer more than one year ago, i just want to add other solution for this problem, to fix R.id.snack in radio button example from apidemo, you must to add file, named : ids.xml on your values's folder and put this code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<resources>
  <item type="id" name="snack" />
</resources>
```